# How exclude undesireble function type as argument?

Tags: typescript, function, generics, typescript-generics

I have a function that filters out a function argument of only one type: with no parameters.

```
type F = <T>(a: (() => T) | Exclude<T, (...args: any[]) => any>) => void;

declare const f: F;
```

Mostly this solution works well:

```
const c1 = f(() => 1); // all good
const c2 = f<1>(() => 1); // all good
const c3 = f((x: 1) => x); // error
const c4 = f<1>((x: unknown) => x); // error
const c5 = f<1>((x: 1) => x); // error
```

except these cases:

```
const c6 = f((x: unknown) => x); //  I want it to be error but no warning
const c7 = f<unknown>((x: unknown) => x); // I want it to be error but no warning
const c8 = f<unknown>((x: 1) => x); //  I want it to be error but no warning
```

How to make it work?

UPD: It is possible to embrace some edge cases to make them work. The downside is the solution is too verbose and it does not cover all edge cases:

```
type F = <T, P = never>(
  a: [P] extends [never]
    ? Param<T>
    : ((...forbiddenArgs: [any, ...any[]]) => any) extends P
    ? never
    : P & Param<T>
) => void;

type Param<T> = (() => T) | Exclude<T, (...args: any) => any>;

declare const f: F;

const c1 = f(() => 1); // all good
const c2 = f<1>(() => 1); // all good
const c3 = f((x: 1) => x); // error
const c4 = f<1>((x: unknown) => x); // error
const c5 = f<1>((x: 1) => x); // error
const c6 = f((x: unknown) => x); // now it results in an error!!!
const c7 = f<unknown>((x: unknown) => x); // error wanted
const c8 = f<unknown>((x: 1) => x); // error wanted
```

UPD2: The different approach  is to break ambiguous types (`unknown`, `object`, `{}`) onto basic types:

```
type F = <T>(a: Param<T>) => void;

type Param<T> =
  | (() => T)
  | ({} extends T
      ? BasicTypes extends infer IBT
        ? IBT extends T
          ? IBT
          : never
        : never
      : Exclude<T, (...args: any) => any>);

type BasicTypes =
  | string
  | number
  | bigint
  | boolean
  | symbol
  | Record<any, unknown>
  | undefined
  | null;

declare const f: F;

const c1 = f(() => 1); // all good
const c2 = f<1>(() => 1); // all good
const c3 = f((x: 1) => x); // error
const c4 = f<1>((x: unknown) => x); // error
const c5 = f<1>((x: 1) => x); // error
const c6 = f((x: unknown) => x); // now it results in an error!!!
const c7 = f<unknown>((x: unknown) => x); // now it results in an error!!!
const c8 = f<unknown>((x: 1) => x); // now it results in an error!!!
```

It works in almost every case:

```
const c9 = f(1); // ok
const c10 = f({ a: 1 }); // ok
const c11 = f<object>(1); // error
const c12 = f<object>({ a: 1 }); // ok
const c13 = f<{}>(1); // ok
const c14 = f<{}>(null); // error
const c15 = f<unknown>(null); // ok
```

...until it encounters simple interfaces:

```
const c16 = f(new Map()); //ok
const c17 = f<unknown>(new Map()); // error but must be ok!!!
```

It is because `Map` interface does not extends `Record<any, unknown>`:

```
type Check = Map<any, any> extends Record<any, unknown> ? true : false; // false;
```

Only interfaces with defined `string` keys work:

```
interface NewMap extends Map<any, any> {
  [K: string]: unknown;
}

const c18 = f<unknown>(new Map() as NewMap) // ok
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgglAvFAPAFQHwAoCGAuKLLASiQyjVIB8oBRADwGMAbAVwBMJ0AaQgOgE4ATgHMAzgRwA7EAG0AuqUTlpIDEvIA3APYBLdgG4AUEc4th0RtqljgUAGb5YcY0as27jHAEYkDnEQaUN7Exu62UF4ATH6OKN7YJGTBoUYA9GlQAALAYgC0EPSQjMAFQkLaQm7WEV4AzLEBWPQEIcn0qRnZuQVFECVlFVXhnjgALI3xiS1QrFIA1lLaAO5SQR3GXTn5hcWlEOWV1R6ROACskwlEM23KUBvpmdu9e4NHI6cAbI3XBHOLKzW7U6Tx6u36%200OwxqowA7JN-ktVtM-gskUC7g8tmC%20gMDkNjrUcAAOBFowEolLAsIw04ATh%20IRpJy83gADD8AN5QJy%20AC%20IO6O1xkIJH1ZvmQcW0ACMAFYQ7BMwmjbwxKU4FCyhUlbDc3lQAXMoneBoalCcvlKwXPcF4qEq07eCbmy3YKSsZjMVLinwXc2IilYD1en201nfDXBiDLKAAWRwYBIYZZPnhAfJyOjsYTSeIqSMoEgsAAQn4eFAAAp%20KQQTQHbBGKDNnkEWSV%20RQQrACBSdhiKCyWv1oTyJsticAfirwhwAFsS%20gMOOJ82CEQBHx7JUZfpOFI4KIJIPVLxN6oFIpkqpSN3e-2qyvV9PhwcnxOCNWAGQzoTzxeYEYQQ6PorhFtAlazguS5%20IEySUFANAMCwHBcGgvBYOeR6SDIQSqBgrhmMwFiRLS9gygQMAlq44oypKDgynBdzKrR6oMVMTHkMq2LCq8%20LvOGMpmgxvxUpiNo4nxDq0S67FXM0qIAqs6wSbxEJvNCLIyv6cmUrc5BYqCan2mKgmRiJCmzJmGIGapLzqfxmm1DK6bsYGWaWe5Nn3HZdqigJWmklKMooF5ekqcangygywVYCxgnsrEjH6q0hq%20SKGmOowdH0eRWryoqcUps5apJflOrAHqrbBGlkWRHRwl5W6RWbEZ9kmQFJWyU1VrBp63p1dl3g6XlYV9aGg10eZ5HZvGibJpN3iuaN1nujGc15gW4GwAAwuWmC4J%20UE7UuwF6IYJjbZBf5zidmBIE%20NCcRQxCPYQlpdvQPZ9gOaDvi204ljgYi6IwaDgBAA53j9UC6FI9gHFAACSJZ-auAPI6jn3fQ%20aPo1A04o3j6MEK%20VT41ApN1m%20FMEMhbCcBWmGCNhPK4deMjqGBENQEDINgxDA6IG9thCHDIhvR6c4yjTLY0LuIhw8Ab0yto2jMBA0giyA0vq29ABK-SVOwKCnlZSlSMuE40HMnD2HDEDsJL-WEf0xFCJYZGMJRO00eGjC5Ywz3xSyjBsfYjAcUkzHpVJpmh41QeWfpPmtUK7X%20U5niMN1kfyTMXkRY86d%20Zl4qMCNefhdSxe2hljlZYw01JwX1lFzxGdl-7y2R2NnltzXHelw35dBQ4veraJKcPOXMXjy1jeJVKQcpTVRq15JDnSf73iB%20VhUh7UAfh5H2qFav-LFdnpqxJHzXcW1w-b6Hzq3xavUhgNi%20V6Fk%20f1fkQA7N1mrmBai8e6-wtmtHM818yuBMEAA)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Could you please explain why last three examples should have an error?

Comment: Also, `f(1)`, your function may accept primitive value. Is it expectable?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I edited. New read is "I want it to be error but no warning". This is a task the solution of which is a solution to my question.

Comment: > Also, f(1), your function may accept primitive value. Is it expectable? - Yes, it is. This is why it is so difficult to find the full solution to my question. I can improve it  to include some edge cases but not for all.

Comment: I think it would be great if you could elaborate a bit more. Right now the question is very terse and it is a bit difficult to deduce what you actually desire. Additionally describing why it is not working and why you want it to give an error could actually help us get more insight into what you want the solution to be.

Comment: I don't fully understand why yet, but this seems to do what you desire. I think the added level of indirection might somehow help.

`type C<T> = () => T | T;
type F = <T>(a: C<T>) => void;`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `Exclude` to the parameter of the function. The idea is to have a function, that accepts an argument. If the argument is a function it must have no argument itself.

Comment: @AndreiKovalev in what way does `type C<T> = () => T | T; type F = <T>(a: C<T>) => void;` differ from what you aim to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible

Answer (score 2):

I hesitate to answer this, because it's not clear that you know what you're attempting to achieve. If this is a suitable answer, please reword it to a specific question rather than a list of things that didn't work.

Your function type `F` needs a generic parameter that represents the argument passed to it. Any inference about whether that argument is a function -- and if so, what it returns -- would be a separate concern.

To answer the objective in your comment:

> The idea is to have a function, that accepts an argument. If the
> argument is a function it must have no argument itself.

You can use:

```
type Arg<A> =
  A extends () => any ? A :
  A extends (...args: [any, ...any]) => any ? never :
  A;

export type F = <T>(arg: Arg<T>) => void;
```

This precludes any `T` where `T` is a function with arguments, but allows any no-arg function or any non-function. It's not particularly useful within an implementation of `F`, however.

I'm assuming here that you would actually want the implementation of such an `F` to be able to conditionally handle either type, in which case you want an overload:

```
type NonFunction<T> = T extends (...args: any) => any ? never : T;

export type F = {
  <T>(arg: () => T): T;          // `T` is the result of the function
  <T>(arg: NonFunction<T>): T;   // `T` is the argument itself, which cannot be a function
}
```

The implementation would then omit the generics and have type guards internally to differentiate the cases. For example, this would return either the supplied value, or if it's a (no-arg) function, it's result:

```
const f: F = (arg: any) => {
  if (typeof arg === 'function') {
    return arg();
  } else {
    return arg;
  }
}
const funcResult: string = f(() => 'foo');
const valueResult: string = f('foo');
```

FWIW, I don't see a need in any of these cases to explicitly declare the generic type parameter, but if you do, it would simply be a useless cast to some less-specific type of whatever the parameter is. E.g. these would be equivalent:

```
const withGeneric = f<unknown>(new Map());
const simpleCast: unknown = f(new Map());
```

(Note: the `// @ts-expect-error` directive "inverts" compilation, so any line following it MUST be an error. This is useful e.g. in tests if you want to explicitly check that certain things WILL NOT compile).

```
const c1 = f(() => 1);
const c2 = f(() => 1);
// @ts-expect-error incorrect type
const c3 = f((x: 1) => x);
// @ts-expect-error incorrect type
const c4 = f<1>((x: unknown) => x);
// @ts-expect-error incorrect type
const c5 = f<1>((x: 1) => x);
// @ts-expect-error incorrect type
const c6 = f((x: unknown) => x);
// @ts-expect-error incorrect type
const c7 = f((x: unknown) => x);
// @ts-expect-error incorrect type
const c8 = f((x: 1) => x);
const c9 = f(1);
const c10 = f({ a: 1 });
// @ts-expect-error incorrect type
const c11 = f<object>(1);
const c12 = f<object>({ a: 1 });
const c13 = f<{}>(1);
const c14 = f<{}>(null);
const c15 = f<unknown>(null);
const c16 = f(new Map());
const c17 = f<unknown>(new Map());
```

Comment: I see my question needs more clarification. Basically, your proposed solution is not better than what I added in the updated section of my question. You skipped this part: `const c7 = f<unknown>((x: unknown) => x)` of validation. I understand your concern that it is not a practical case. But the question itself came out from the bigger problem. I just narrowed down this big question to the more generic one. And it is important for the answer to cover the use case above. To illustrate why it is so important I composed the following example in a playground. It is based on your solution.

Comment: When I said your solution is not better than mine I mean it is not getting me closer to resolving the question. But your realization is definitely more preferable due to it is less verbose and more elegant.

Comment: Your sandbox has nothing to do with the original question and only a passing resemblance to my answer. It doesn't work because you've broken the behavior. With the additional type parameter on `F`, you're now casting the second argument to "whatever type `M[K]` is", which in the last example is `unknown`. It's the same as your case above `f<unknown>(anything)`. You're explicitly telling the compiler "that's not a function, it's an `unknown`", which satisfies the condition "not a function with arguments".

Comment: Actually, it does. If you resolve the original question without the skipping the use case I mentioned you can resolve the example from sandbox. And vice versa.They are perfectly connected. Just read my "upd2" where I was the most close to the solution.

Comment: And it is not just "whatever type M[K] is". K is inferred from the passing argument which way I avoided passing the explicit generic value to the function that you called useless for the reason.

Comment: Type parameters are either inferred, or they're explicitly specified. Never both. When you call `f` without a type parameter, it will attempt to infer it. When you call `f<unknown>`, you're telling the compiler, "you don't have to infer anything. I'm telling you it's `unknown`" no matter what you pass in there. When you type the argument as "the type of the value of `M[K]`", and `M[K]` is `unknown`, it's no different. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: `M[K]` might be whatever you want but you don't know in advance. When it happens to be `unknown` the construction no longer works. That's it.